# Importing csv using Flume

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am trying to import a csv file into HDFS using flume. 
but I am getting "line length exceeds max 2048" this warning and lines are getting truncated. 
Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this issue.

following is my source file--

```
a1.sources = s
a1.channels = c
a1.sinks = sk

a1.sources.s.type = spooldir
a1.sources.s.spoolDir = /home/itelligence/Desktop/Project 2

a1.channels.c.type = file

a1.sinks.sk.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.sk.hdfs.path = /project 2
a1.sinks.sk.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

a1.sources.s.channels = c
a1.sinks.sk.channel = c
```

---

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your source file

```
a1.sources.s.deserializer.maxLineLength = <MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH>
```